# Установил ubuntu на один диск с виндой, после чего винда перестала запускаться

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, bios

есть один жесткий диск, на 7-ой винде выделил несколько разделов, на один из них я поставил убунту, после этого винда перестала запускаться, попробовал установить образ 7-ой винды на флешку и переустановить винду, но при выборе флешки в биосе запускается grub, в инете ответов не нашел, поэтому прошу вас помочь, что делать??????????????????? Если не сделаю, мой босс меня убьет!11!!!!!!!!

Comment: Собственно вопрос "зачем?" тут явно не уместен. Есть подозрение, что в процессе установки вы затерли виндовый раздел. Сделайте загрузочную флешку с gparted и в биосе выставите загрузку с usb.

Comment: попробуй в ебунте установить [grub-customizer](https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/grub_customizer). там можно будет выбрать варианты загрузки ос

Comment: @becouse, так при загрузке с usb загружается grub, который не дает запуститься флешке

Comment: Это значит, что у вас не идет загрузка с флешки. Установите в биосе приоритет загрузки.

Comment: @becouse, установил, ничего не изменилось

Comment: Из убунты видны виндовые диски и информация на них?

Comment: @Morewind, как понять видны? Флешки формата ntfs читаются, я на них даже фильмы в убунту скачивал

Comment: Если убунта установлена рядом с виндовс (а не поверх) то в убунтовском проводнике должны показываться диски с файлами из виндовс раздела. Ну а если убунта установлена поверх - то ой, винда пропала. При загрузке убунта не спрашивает откуда грузится? Как вариант попробовать это https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/boot_repair

Comment: @Morewind, нет, убунта не установилась поверх винды, я спокойно могу прочитать виндосовские файлы

Comment: Пр установке ОС с grub на ЖД где уже есть WBM grub вроде сам законфигится как надо))) grub config почитайте

Comment: @helpme  "я спокойно могу прочитать виндосовские файлы". Т.е. виндовс раздел сохранился. Вывод: проблема в настройках grub. При загрузке у Вас появляется меню выбора ОС? Если нет - то это означает, что задана по умолчанию загрузка люних, а время показа меню задано == 0. Задайте время показа меню хотя бы секунд 5 и всё будет ОК.